# show for a graph with $60$ vertices and minimum degree of $41$ must contain a $4$-complete subgraph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I got this question in my HW, trying to prove it using the pigeonhole principle but with no luck, any clues would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose an arbitrary point $p_1$.  It has at least $41$ neighbors, and therefore at most $18$ non-neighbors.

Let's call the set of neighbors $A$.  Choose an arbitrary element $p_2 \in A$.  It can have at most $18$ non-neighbors, so at least $22$ of its neighbors are also in $A$.

Let's call this set $B$ and observe that $B \subseteq A$.  Choose an arbitrary point in $p_3 \in B$.  $B$ has at least $21$ other points.  We know that two of its neighbors are $p_1$ and $p_2$.  It has at most $18$ non-neighbors, so at least $1$ element of $B$ other than $p_1$ and $p_2$ must be a neighbor of $p_3$.  But each element of $B$ is also a neighbor of $p_1$ and $p_2$, so we are done.

Note, by the way, this proves the stronger result that *every* point of the graph is a vertex of a $4$-complete subgraph.